# Simple AJAX Function Issue: How does server receive message from client automatically?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I read some tutorials from w3school about ajax. I assume that how does server receive message from client automatically. I have two pages, one is for client and one is for server. When someone type something and click submit, then the server page will automatically append on the screen. This is what I use:

```
client:
<script>
$(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
$.post("server.html", $("#f1").value()+"&&"+$("#f2").value(), function(){
alert("send!");
});
});
});
</script>
<input type="number" name="f1" id="f1" placeholder="first number..." />
<input type="number" name="f2" id="f2" placeholder="second number..." />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />

server:
$(function(){
$("#pmsg").hide();
$("#msg").load("client.html", function(){
$("#pmsg").show().delay(1000).hide();
});

});
<div id="pmsg">new message</div>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

I can't achieve the result that I want, could someone tell me how to fix it? thx!

**I solved the problem. I use php to write the message into a txt file and then use $.get to get the message from that file.**

Comment: You didn't understand AJAX at all? Where is you server side content?

Answer (score 0):

You are basically using the jQuery liberary and its load function to do the ajax work. 
It actually work like this:
It create the http object as per browser (for IE - activexobject, FF - xmlhttprequest) and send the request to url that we are called as server site. 
There are four states:

```
0: request not initialized
1: server connection established
2: request received
3: processing request
4: request finished and response is ready
```

Below is the code:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```